# Как мне вывести русский язык с помощью MessageBox

Tags: c++, c, winapi, messagebox

Пытаюсь вызвать MessageBox функцию Win32 , но она отображает иероглифы.

Аргументы:
`NULL, (LPCSTR)Line.c_str(), (LPCSTR)Line.c_str(), NULL`

Но самое главное, я заметил баг что ли:

1)Если я создам строку вот так: `string Line = "Hello" - она будет отображаться как надо!!!`

2)Если создам строку так: `string Line; cin >> Line;` - отображаются иероглифы!!!

В чем подвох? Пожалуйста, решите или предложите что-нибудь !!!

`string Line = "Nice bro!!!";`

`MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)Line.c_str() , (LPCSTR)Line.c_str(), NULL); // работает`

`string Line;`

`cin >> Line;`

`MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)Line.c_str() , (LPCSTR)Line.c_str(), NULL); // не работает`

Comment: Вам стоит использовать кодировку UTF16 и отказаться от `MessageBoxA` и диких катов типа `(LPCSTR)Line.c_str()`.

Answer (score 0):

Подвох при вводе русскоязычного текста заключается в том, что консоль по умолчанию имеет кодировку DOS (cp866), а MessageBoxA() выводит текст в кодировке Windows (cp1251). Путей решения как минимум три.

Путь 1. Перед вводом с консоли измените её кодировку, например сделав вызов `SetConsoleCP(1251)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string Line = "Nice bro!!!";
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)Line.c_str() , (LPCSTR)Line.c_str(), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION); // работает

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    cin >> Line;
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)Line.c_str() , (LPCSTR)Line.c_str(), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION); // тоже работает

    return 0;
}
```

Путь 2. После ввода с консоли преобразовать строку в кодировку 1251, вызвав функцию `OemToCharA()` (см. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-oemtochara).

Путь 3. Работать со строками UNICODE.

P.S. Последний параметр MessageBox() не NULL, а 0. А ещё лучше что-нибудь вроде MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION.

Comment: Причина диза?..

Comment: это не я - у меня маленькая репутация чтобы ставить оценку. А твой ответ замечательный, ты просто бог отвечаю. Просто пишу свою библиотеку и добрался до WinApi и до MessageBox и начался Magic какой-то :D спасибо, тоисть получается я могу теперь работать с русскими путями например DeleteFile, CreateDirectory?

Comment: Так понятно, что не вы ставите, тут свои редиски имеются)) Да, с русскими путями иметь дело можете, так как для ASCII они также работают в 1251. Однако намного корректнее тогда работать не с ASCII, а с UNICODE, так как в этом случае вы не будете зависеть от локализации системы, да и пути к файлам в этом случае не будут ограничиваться английским и русским языками. И да, научитесь пользоваться поиском, в инете на эту тему всё есть. За это скорее всего и минусуют, за дубли.

Comment: Хм, ну если брать в расчет допустим именно русскую локализацию, то там да, возможно cp866 и стоит, но это не обязательно. Недавно после некоторых обновлений на рабочей машине (не в русской локализации), по умолчанию встала кодировка utf-8.

Comment: @こきん да, такое бывает. По-этому и написал в посте выше, что для мутльтиязычных строк лучше использовать UNICODE - надёжнее и универсальнее.

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых случаях мало изменить кодировку консоли через `SetConsoleCP(1251)`, нужно поменять ещё и шрифт, чтобы он поддерживал кириллицу, типа "LucidaConsole".

Comment: Ну шрифт программно особо нет смысла менять, так как пользователь всегда может сделать это в настройках внешнего вида консоли. Если так рассуждать, то и системный шрифт может быть не локализованным под русский язык, в этом случае пользователь будет видеть иероглифы во многих русскоязычных приложениях, которые не используют unicode.

Comment: Я сталкивался с такой проблемой, когда пытался открыть в консоли текстовый документ Win-1251. Тогда функция `SetConsoleCP(1251)` отрабатывала нормально, а на консоль так и вываливались кракозябры. Оказалось, что шрифт стоит без поддержки кирилицы.